# (Warning: Contract code size exceeds 24576 bytes) Pops on Hardhat but not Remix

Tags: solidity, hardhat

Remix compiles the code without the warning using their optimized but hardhat throws an error "(Warning: Contract code size exceeds 24576 bytes)"

```
Hardhat config:
module.exports = {
  solidity: "0.8.7",
  settings: {
    optimizer: {
      enabled: true,
      runs: 500,
      details: { yul: false },
    },
  }....
```

What could be an issue?
How to tackle it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to mention the optimization settings inside the version since hardhat execute

multiple solidity version code.

Example for single version settings

```
module.exports = {
      solidity: {
        version: "0.8.9",
        settings: {
          optimizer: {
            enabled: true,
            runs: 1000,
          },
        },
      },
    };
```

For multiple version support settings

```
solidity: {
    compilers: [
      {
        version: "0.6.12",
      },
      {
        version: "0.5.16",
      },
      {
        version: "0.6.6",
        settings: {
          optimizer: {
            enabled: true,
            runs: 1000,
          },
        },
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

Comment: kanye yeezy, you're a genius, you did it again 